# my output doesn't go to database due to "syntax erron in insert into statement"

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

```
 myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
 myConnection.Open()
 Dim str As String
 str = "Insert into connect([jersey],[Fname],[Mname],[Lname]) Values (?,?,?,?)"
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("jersey", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Fname", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Mname", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Lname", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
 Try
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     cmd.Dispose()
     myConnection.Close()
     TextBox1.Clear()
     TextBox2.Clear()
     TextBox3.Clear()
     TextBox4.Clear()
  Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
```

Comment: _Connect_ is a reserved keyword. You need to use square brackets around it as you do for the fields

Comment: Side note: `TextBox.Text` is already a string, this is really useless: `CType(TextBox1.Text, String)` -- Side side note: don't use common terms to name your Object (Tables, Fields, whatever). Add, e.g., a prefix (as `tblConnect`, `fldJersey`) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

CONNECT is a [`Access database engine reserved word`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2)

Put square brackets around and it should work.

```
Insert into [connect] ([jersey],[Fname],[Mname],[Lname]) Values (?,?,?,?)
```